# Cartoon about 4 kids that go into a digital world and fighting with an army

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, animated-series

There was this one cartoon that I can't remember the name to, but this is how it went: There were 4 kids, and they had some sort of magic talismans that would transport them to a digital world, and here they would fight in a war with troops on their side and the enemy side, and the villain had a few generals that had better powers, and every episode he would send one or more of them. They would die, but they would then come back a few episodes later, because the villain had this thing that made them respawn.

The main characters would have to fight every episode until they realized that they could destroy that respawn thing. And that's how the last few episodes went. I can't remember the name, but I want to rewatch the series, so does anyone know what this is?

It’s not Code Lyoko or Di-Gata Defenders.

Comment: do you remember when you watched this?  Anything you can do to narrow down the time frame would help.  Also would help to now where to saw it

Comment: i dont remember when i watched it but i know i watched it on nextflix but they removed it

Comment: Would you have watched this within the last five years, or more like 10-15 years ago? Also, was the show entirely animated, or were there parts that were live-action? And was the animation 2D or 3D?

Comment: it was aired 2008

Comment: had a simular animation to code lyoko

Comment: if you have access to the netflix account that you watched it in, you could probably find it in the watch history this will be quite the slog since you don't remember when you watched it..